# lambda is slower than function call in python, why

Tags: python, function, lambda

I think lambda is faster than function call, but after testing, I find out that I am wrong. Function call is definitely faster than lambda call.

Can anybody tell me why?

And how to speed up function call in Python?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.6

```
>>> timeit('def a():return 222*333 ;a()')
0.08195090293884277
>>> timeit('a=lambda:222*333 ;a()')
0.11071300506591797

>>> timeit('a=lambda: [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')
0.40241098403930664
>>> timeit('a=lambda: [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')
0.4011270999908447
>>> timeit('a=lambda: [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')
0.4064619541168213
>>> timeit('def a(): return [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')
0.07965493202209473
>>> timeit('def a(): return [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')
0.08039593696594238
>>> timeit('def a(): return [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')
0.08103609085083008
>>> timeit('def a(): return [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')
0.08639097213745117
```

---

Sorry for my mistake, there is no difference. Correct testing:

```
>>> timeit('a()', setup="def a():return 222*333")
0.07061290740966797
>>> timeit('a()', setup="a=lambda: 222*333")
0.06967616081237793
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`timeit('def a(): return [].extend(range(10)) ;a()')` is not calling `a()`; The call to `a()` is part of the definition of `a`:

```
In [34]: def a(): return [].extend(range(10)) ;a()

In [35]: import dis

In [36]: dis.dis(a)
  1           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (extend)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
             19 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (a)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            0       #<-- a is called
             25 POP_TOP
```

---

If you test the pieces separately, the difference is negligible:

```
In [24]: %timeit a=lambda: [].extend(range(10))
10000000 loops, best of 3: 68.6 ns per loop

In [25]: %timeit def a2(): return [].extend(range(10))
10000000 loops, best of 3: 68.8 ns per loop

In [22]: %timeit a()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 445 ns per loop

In [23]: %timeit a2()
1000000 loops, best of 3: 442 ns per loop
```

Comment: Sorry for my stupid mistake... I ran this testing, there is no definitely difference.   `>>> timeit('a()', setup="def a():return 222*333")
0.07061290740966797
>>> timeit('a()', setup="a=lambda: 222*333")
0.06967616081237793
`

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out above, your first test only profiles the time it takes to *define* `a`. It's actually never called.

Lambda expressions and "normal" functions generate the exact same bytecode, as you can see if you use the `dis` module:

```
def a(): return 10
b = lambda: 10

import dis

>>> dis.dis(a)
1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
            3 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b)
1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
            3 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: This is an important point.  People sometimes think "lambda functions" are a special kind of thing, but they're not: `lambda` is simply a keyword used to make a plain old function, mostly handy because it can be used inline.  That's it.  They don't have magic powers.

Comment: @DSM Actually lambdas are equivalent to the more restricted case of a function containing a single return statement.  So compiling a lambda might be a little simpler than compiling a function.

Comment: @augurar: that's the first time I've ever heard someone suggest that an advantage of lambdas (or any syntactic choice in Python, really) is simpler _compilation_.  Anyway, the point isn't that a lambda can be used to make any function, it's that what the lambda keyword creates _is_ a function, and not a "lambda function".

Answer (score 8):

There's no difference in calling a lambda versus a function. A lambda is just a function created with a single expression and no name.

Say we have two identical functions, one created with a function definition, the other with a lambda expression:

```
def a():
    return 222*333

b = lambda: 222*333
```

We see that both are the same type of function object and they both share equivalent byte-code:

```
>>> type(a)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(b)
<class 'function'>

>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(a)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (73926)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(b)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (73926)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

How can you speed that up? You don't. It's Python. It's ***pre-optimized*** for you. There's nothing more for you to do with this code.

Perhaps you could give it to another interpreter, or rewrite it in another language, but if you're sticking to Python, there's nothing more to do now.

### Timing it

Here's how I would examine the timings.

Timeit's `timeit` and `repeat` both take a callable:

```
import timeit
```

Note that `timeit.repeat` takes a `repeat` argument as well:

```
>>> min(timeit.repeat(a, repeat=100))
0.06456905393861234
>>> min(timeit.repeat(b, repeat=100))
0.06374448095448315
```

These differences are too small to be significant.