# Does Lambda function not required?

Tags: python, lambda

I need some opinions about lambda function in python.

I have been using Lambda function in python. For example, `DirList = [i for i in tmp if "PC" in i]`.
However today I heard that one lecturer said that lambda function is not required in python3.

I have been taught that if I use lambda properly, my code can be more efficient because rather than using statement(if, for, etc.), lambda is treated as an expression which causes less computational burden. But now I'm confused about whether I should use lambda.

Comment: "I have been taught that if I use lambda properly, my code can be more efficient because rather than using statement(if, for, etc.), lambda is treated as an expression which causes less computational burden." that is definitely not correct.  Also, your example of a lambda `DirList = [i for i in tmp if "PC" in i]` doesn't use a lambda expression at all. In any case, yes, `lambda` expressions are not *necessary*, though *sometimes* people prefer them for convenience/readability. For what it's worth, Guido wanted to remove `lambda` from Python 3

Comment: The example you give has nothing to do with "lambda function"s. If you were using a lambda, your code would have the actual word `lambda` in it. Because of this, it's not clear what you're talking about. Is the example wrong? Or are you really talking about *list comprehensions*? In which case, are you sure that you understood what the lecturer was talking about?

Comment: Again, if you *are* talking about list comprehensions, those are also not required. They are mildly faster, but that's isn't the primary reason to use them. Rather, they should be used to improve readability. As the amount of work per iteration increases then that advantage disappears anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no difference in the speed of both functions ref: [lambda is slower than function call in python, why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540885/lambda-is-slower-than-function-call-in-python-why) (spoiler alert, it's not)

A lambda is just a function created with a single expression and no name.